# Joining Tables With Conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables on joining condition plus two conditions. One is from first table and second is from another:

```
select * from `property_master`,`property_type_lookup`
WHERE `property_master`.`propertyType`=`property_type_lookup`.`property_type` AND `CityName`='Delhi' AND `property_type_lookup`.`property_group`='commercial';
```

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: So what issue you are facing ? Getting any error ? Not getting data ? Be specific while asking question and provide some sample data with expected output.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 2nd condition is not executing

Comment: So provide some sample data and expected output from that.

Comment: it just showing filtered result of first condition ie `CityName`='Delhi'

Comment: it just showing two tables joined by joining condition but third condition `property_type_lookup`.`property_group`='commercial' doesn't take any effect

Comment: @AshishPatil its virtually impossible to guess what you are trying to achieve without seeing the sample data and expected output. I dont think it will take more than 2 minutes to share those information. Or wait for some magician to solve your issue.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty  it simply gives data like this  [table 1 data] [table 2 data]   it must not show data where property_group other than the value i have specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be showing you all properties that are commercial, and are in dehli.  If you want all buildings in dehli, and all commercial buildings wherever they are, change it to this:

```
select * from property_master pm
  inner join property_type_lookup pl
    on pm.propertyType = pl.property_type
  where cityname = 'delhi'
    OR pl.property_group = 'commercial';
```

If you want something else.. you're going to have to explain it better

**EDIT**

If you want all commercial buildings in dehli, the query (using join syntax, rather than implicit joins) is this:

```
select * from property_master pm
  inner join property_type_lookup pl
    on pm.propertyType = pl.property_type
  where cityName = 'Dehli' 
    and property_group = 'Commercial'
```

Here is my best shot at a fiddle demonstrating what I think you want:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7513c/4

Comment: in that case, can you please provide an example of your tables, and your data at http://sqlfiddle.com ? as well as a detailed example of what you want the result to look like?

Comment: is any other method to make it possible

Comment: well, you could describe exactly what you want the results to look like?

Comment: Thanks @pala_ with AND it works fine.It might be server error.